Errors occurs during installation
Anyone support to resolve issue in installing
here is my code Docker file
FROM node:latest
WORKDIR /myapp
COPY . /myapp/
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
Errors:

[4/4] RUN npm install:
0.895 npm error code ENOENT
0.895 npm error syscall open
0.895 npm error path /myapp/package.json
0.896 npm error errno -2
0.896 npm error enoent Could not read package.json: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/myapp/package.json'
0.896 npm error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
0.896 npm error enoent
0.899 npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2024-07-29T19_57_38_203Z-debug-0.log


dockerfile:7
5 |     COPY . /myapp/
6 |
7 | >>> RUN npm install
8 |
9 |     EXPOSE 3000
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c npm install" did not complete successfully: exit code: 254
Expecting to install Successful react based app
